# How to solve, UIAlertController (ActionSheet) is Crashed on iPad in xamarin.ios native app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have implemented `UIAlertController` in our xamarin.ios native app and its work fine in iPhone but its crash on iPad.
Please guide to solve this issue. our code is,

```
var alertController = UIAlertController.Create(null, "Select", UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Photo/Image", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => { 
             /* handle your action */  
}

alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Files", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => { 
             /* handle your action */  
}

PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
```

its working fine in iPhone but crashed on iPad...Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your kind information you can't present alert controller for ipad you can use something which is called popovers

here are some links

[popover github example](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/Popovers)

[xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86057/popover-or-dropdown-for-iphone-ipad)

Comment: How to implement popovers in C#..we got code in swift but want to same in C#. just little bit modification required in above code via checking idiom()

Comment: did you checked links check this links also:- https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/ios8/UIKitEnhancements/UIKitEnhancements/PopoverViewController.cs

Comment: Yes i am working on it. I will let you know later..thanks